# When I run the project it terminates before doing anything

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, eclipse-cdt

This Is my 1st project in C++ so could be missing something basic but here is my problem

When I click my project and select run as local c/C++ project it pops up with a dialog that disappears before i can get any idea what it might say. Unlike project i have done before the console does not open (as Im guessing it should), however if I have it open already it displays nothing and acts as if it has already finished.
Below are some of the main methods I have tried:

The one I actually need:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "GasStation.h"
using namespace controller;

int main() {
GasStationTUI myTUI;
myTUI.run();
return 0;
}
```

But I also try for testing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "GasStation.h"
using namespace controller;  

int main() {
cout<<"stuff"<<endl;
cin.get(); /or/ system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Also it it help here is the run method and the method it calles:

```
void GasStationTUI::run() {
this->displayOptions();
    }
string GasStationTUI::displayOptions() {
string selection;
cout << "Welcome to the Gas Station Finder." << endl;
cout
        << "What would you like to query: (m)iminum price, ma(x)imum price, (p)repay pumps,"
        << endl;
cout << "(t)hreshold price, (l)ist stations, (q)uit " << endl;
cin >> selection;
return selection;}
```

Also I have another project that was given to me that SHOULD be working but it is have the same error making me think it might be something other then my code.

Lastly yes I have cleaned and fully built the project(s) multiple times with no change.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Honestly not what I wanted to hear I have know idea how to fix it other wise

Comment: Try running it from the console to see what is displayed (if you launch the console manually it wont close by itself when the execution is over)

Comment: Sorry but you would have to walk me through how to do that

Comment: On windows, run Command Prompt, navigate using `cd` to your folder where your application is built and type its name to launch it

Comment: Ok so I go in to the project folder then type the name of the project?
If so then the message reads 'Project' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: You probably need to go like `Project\Debug` and then type `myprojectname.exe`

Comment: Also, try learning how to use a debugger

Comment: wait Project\Debug? in cmd or in eclipse?

Comment: In cmd... I was referring to the path where your project gets built

Comment: Sorry about this I almost never use the cmd. My project is on the desktop in a folder called project 1 and the exe is called JamesThompsonGasStationFinder could you spell it out for me?

Comment: open a cmd window, and using the windows explorer go to where you are storing your exe and just drag it and drop it into the cmd, then Enter.